# Modifying an existing time formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, time, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have the following formula that I need adjusting and not sure what to do:

```
=IF(TIME(8,0,0)-A1=30/1440,TIME(8,0,0),A1)
```

If I enter `7:30` or `8:00` in cell A1 a value of `8:00` is returned.  What I want to do now is also add `8:30`.  Which means when I enter `7:30`, `8:00` or `8:30` the value of `8:00` should be returned.

Can one of you assist me with that?

Comment: @pnuts, is that the actual link you wanted to share here?

Comment: Oh, I would have commented that link in that question then. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to find a solution for my issue

```
With ActiveSheet

    .Range("$A$1:$Y$993").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">" & 1 / 10 ^ 10
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=7.5/24,A1<=8.5/24),8/24,A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=IF(ABS(A1-TIME(8,0,0))*24<=0.5,TIME(8,0,0),A1)
```

Although there might be some rounding issues. For example, in my case, `(8:30-8:00)*24` gives me 0.500000000000001.

Do you need to do more calculations like this? If you do, the formula can be generalized.